# How does `tf.image.decode_image` deal with channels in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Does the `channels` in `tf.image.decode_image` must equal to the real channel of images? What would happen if the real channel is greater or less than the `channels` in `tf.image.decode_image`?
If they must be equal, how should I deal with the situation that my image set contains images with different channels?

Answer (score 3):

The channels do not need to be equal but the values are limited to 0, 1, and 3.

0 defaults to the original number of channels in the image.

1 outputs the images as greyscale.

3 outputs the images as RGB.

Update 5-30-2020:

Tensorflow 2.0 [decode_image](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_image) also handles 4 color channel images.

Comment: @bw4sz besides opencv almost all other frameworks read images in as RGB.  It makes debugging easier when your frameworks are not manipulating your data as it is read.  The WYSIWYG paradigm.

Comment: Also, we have 4 which outputs image as RGBA

Comment: In tensorflow 2.0 tf.io.decode_image handles 0,1,3,4 color channel images.